# Replacing an entire object in Knockout Model while maintaining bindings

Tags: knockout.js

I can't seem to find any documentation on KOs website or on Google searches that describe how one might change an entire object in a view model while maintaining bindings.

```
$(function () {
    var stuff = {
        IntroData: {
            SomeObject: {
                Name: 'Hello'
            }
        }
    };

    var someObject = {
        Name: 'World'
    }
    window.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(stuff);
    ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel);

    $("#btnUpdateSomeObject").click(function() {
        try
        {
            window.viewModel.IntroData.SomeObject = ko.mapping.fromJS(someObject);
        } catch(ex) {
            alert("Failure: " + ex.toString());
        }
    });
});
```

I have a non-working fiddle which describes the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/W5X2b/

Is this possible? I feel like this is either a huge drawback to KO or I'm using it inappropriately somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here in your using of `ko.mapping.fromJS`.
So instead of `ko.mapping.fromJS(someObject)`  you should use `ko.mapping.fromJS(someObject, {}, window.viewModel.IntroData.SomeObject);`.

1. `someObject` your updated data.
2. `{}` mapping options.
3. `window.viewModel.IntroData.SomeObject` your target object you want to update.

***[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W5X2b/1/)***

***Update:***
From [KnockoutJS Mapping Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#specifying_the_update_target)

> The third parameter to ko.mapping.fromJS indicates the target

Comment: Ah I didn't realize there was a third parameter option. Thank you very much!

Comment: you welcome, sometimes you need to look deeper in documentation

Comment: I was looking deeper but it turns out I was barking up the wrong tree. The ability to alter an entire object without breaking the bindings seems like it would be a part of the core KO functionality, not a plug in.

Comment: I love you for this. I was scratching my head on how to get this exact problem to working but did not know it was this simple.

Comment: @shriek you welcome .. i have faced this problem twice before

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but SomeObject needs to be an observable.

```
var stuff = {
    IntroData: {
        SomeObject: ko.observable({
            Name: 'Hello'
        })
    }
};
```

As SomeObject is an observable, when you 'set' it ; ko will update the view.

```
window.viewModel.IntroData.SomeObject(ko.mapping.fromJS(someObject));
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W5X2b/2/)

Comment: why `SomeObject needs to be an observable.` ? he is using already ko.mapping which will convert the properties to observales

Comment: If IntroData and SomeObject aren't observables the view won't be refreshed when the data are changed.

Comment: you right, but this is automatically done by mapping plugin. kindly check my [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W5X2b/1/)

Comment: I've upvoted you but while this is correct it's not the approach I'd prefer to take due to the fact that I have a few dozen of these.

Comment: @ebram tharwat, You are right mapping.fromjs(with 3 args) do its job. But when you call ko.mapping.fromJS(stuff) on init. It only converts the Name property to an observable.
I thought the SO wants to set SomeObject and not just the Name property.